# Gerund vs infinitive paraphrase

Tags: differences, infinitives, gerunds, gerund-vs-infinitive

Is there any difference between these two sentences:

1. "The Democrats tend to increase taxes, discouraging rich people from voting for them"
2. "The Democrats tend to increase taxes, which discourages rich poeople from voting for them"

The first version of course sound much more formal, but are there any other (less 'obvious') differences?

Comment: No difference. However, your other wording is off. You discourage people _from_ doing something, not _to_. And the second version should use _which_, not _what_.

Comment: Yes, it's a type of reduced relative clause: which V -> V-ing.  In the example, it's a nonrestrictive relative clause that goes with the verb phrase "increase taxes".

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for your comment and error-spotting, I corrected the question. However, would you agree to Raghuraman's answer?

Comment: Thanks @GregLee, so it's a gramatical difference, but would people care about this one (e.g. in a book, a non-formal conversation/document, ...) or are both ways equally common?

Comment: It's a little odd to say that there's a grammatical difference.  The words are different.  But both examples have nonrestrictive clauses, one is reduced and the other is not reduced.

Answer (score -1):

First, there is no gerund involved here.  2nd version can be or is used in 'spoken' version.  It cannot be used in a written form/version.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to a manual of style that confirms that the second is unacceptable in writing?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my own question confuses me right now... Do you happen to know how to refer to the difference between the two sentences in a more clear or correct way?

Comment: I'd say the ***first*** version is the one that should not be used in formal writing. Can you explain your objections to the second in more detail.

Comment: @Barmar 'The Democrats tend to increase taxes, which discourages rich poeople from voting for them' : The issue is with using 'discourages'.  It should be 'increase taxes, which discourage rich' or 'tax increase, which discourages rich'.

Comment: it depends on whether you think the relative clause refers to taxes (plural) or to the action of increasing them (singular). I interpreted it as the latter, so _discourages_ is correct.